# Can't use If statements and For Statements in the same VBA sub for an Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I nearly have the following array code in vba working, except it only works with the If statement excluded or the "For b. Next b" excluded, and wont work with both in at the same time,

Can someone please help?

```
Sub ReadingRange2()
Dim ARRAY_Multiwage As Variant
Dim ARRAY_TEMP_Multiwage() As Variant
ARRAY_Multiwage = Sheets("Multiwage").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim d As String
Dim s As String

For a = LBound(ARRAY_Multiwage) To UBound(ARRAY_Multiwage)
    s = ARRAY_Multiwage(a, 1)

    If s = "60021184_2018/34/HE" Then
        For b = 1 To 20
            d = d + ARRAY_Multiwage(a, b) + ", "
        Next b
        'Debug.Print StrReverse(Mid(StrReverse(d), 3, 999))
    End If

Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Define "works" and "won't work". What does this code do? Is that correct? What is the other version of the code? What does _that_ do? What is that other result incorrect?

Comment: use & in a srtring:  ==> d = d & ARRAY_Multiwage(a, b) & ", "  (and does your currentregion always have 20+ columns?)

Comment: Hi Underscore_d, sorry, when it works it will print a row with the 20 cols, but when it does not work it gives a runtime error 13.

Comment: @underscore_d,  

Without the IF Statement:
When i comment out the start and end of the IF statement, the code will print out one line which is a row that includes all 20 cols.


Without the For Statement:
it will search for the defined value in the array and print the 1st col of all results found, so if there are six rows with the value, it will print it six times.

What i am wanting it to do... search for the value in the array and copy ALL cols to another Array, but for now just to print it will be good start.

Hope that helps :)